# Debugging Jupyter notebooks in VSCode hangs all the time...what Debug configuration is needed? Any settings that must be manually entered?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger

Debugging my Jupyter notebook in VSCode hangs all the time.  How do I correctly set up Debugging of Jupyter Notebooks in VSCODE?

When launching the debugger, it asks for a debug configuration.  None of the defaults mentions Jupyter notebooks.  There is a Python default configuration which I select.

In the Run and Debug window, I then can launch the debugger using the "play" button.  This always results in this error:

name: 'null' is not defined.

That makes it impossible to run the notebook in the debugger on the notebook and see what happens at the breakpoints.

The other mode of operation is to select "Debug Cell" instead of running the cell.  I then get only one shot at stopping at a breakpoint, inspecting variables and stepping through the code.  Then the following occurs:

- "Step Over" often causes a hang-up
- "Stop", making a change in the code, and then re-running using "Debug Cell" causes a hang-up

Hangup means, the narrow blue busy strip/animation on top of the window is active, but there is no output and the debugger never finishes and allows me to run the next line of code.  I can then stop execution, but in order to resume debugging, I either need to "Restart" or even exit VSCode and relaunch it.

I have googled this issue but not found anything of relevance to Jupyter debugging, other than the VSCode instructions which I follow.

VSCode and libraries are current, especially iPython.  Python version is 3.9.16.

I was expecting to run the debugger on the Notebook (stopping at breakpoints and then correctly resuming).  That does reproducible not work.

When debugging individual cells, after a short while, the debugger hangs and I cannot continue stepping through the code.